# Can't see custom attributes set on a user from their Google_Service_Directory_User object

Tags: google-admin-sdk

When a custom attribute is set on a user from googles admin page I am unable to see it in their Google_Service_Directory_User object the client has this scope and is able to see the users data but no attributes are shown.

```
        $client->setScopes(
            [
                Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_READONLY,
                Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_READONLY,
            ]
        );
```

I would have expected it to be in the customSchemas but that is null for all the users

Answer (score 1):

When requesting user's informations, you need to set the `projection` parameter to `FULL` when using the method users.get (projection parameter is also avaible with method users.list). Default settings to not return custom schemas. You can have more informations [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get?apix_params=%7B%22userKey%22%3A%22pierrecantegril%40sigmathetapi.org%22%2C%22projection%22%3A%22full%22%2C%22viewType%22%3A%22admin_view%22%7D) (Google documentation).

You seem to be using PHP (I've never coded in PHP so I may be wrong), so the request should look like this:

```
$optParams = array(
  'userKey' => 'my_customer@example.com',
  'projection' => 'full', // or maybe 'FULL' ?
);
$results = $service->users->get($optParams);
```

If you only want the return some of the schemas, then use :

```
$optParams = array(
  'userKey' => 'my_customer@example.com',
  'projection' => 'custom', // or maybe 'CUSTOM' ?,
  'customFieldMask' => 'A comma-separated list of schema names'
);
$results = $service->users->get($optParams);
```